# Python: error handling with recursive function in error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my third question. I've already been voted off of the island twice now on stack overflow, so I'm feeling a little iffy about posting.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the below code.

So I have a reference to a function within an error. That is to say, if an error occurs, then the code re-references the function it is entered it runs again. However, when I run it the second time I find that the function does not return the value if both of the inputs are correct (numeric) inputs.

```
    #This is a program that is designed to calculate gross pay:

def main():
    payment = input2()
    print('Gross pay: $', format(payment, ',.2f'), sep='')

def input2():
    try:
        #we're first getting the number of hours that the user is working.

        hours = int(input("How manyu hours did you work?: "))

        pay_rate = int(input("Enter your hourly payrate here: "))

        #display the gross pay
        gross_pay = hours * pay_rate
        payment = gross_pay
        #display the gross pay:
    except ValueError:
        print('Error: Nope')
        input2()
        return payment
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned if there isn't an error? Think: where are you `return`ing here?

Comment: You need a `return payement` statement above `except`

Comment: If you can tell me why you have this in a try-except clause maybe I can help you out. I really don't think you need any recursion for this. Is it just to verify that the two inputs are valid numbers?

Comment: You need to `return input2()` in your exception block. But I would suggest reevaluating whether you should be using recursion here vs. a simple `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is not a good use of recursion, a simple while loop would do:

```
def input2():
    while True:
        try:
            #we're first getting the number of hours that the user is working.
            hours = int(input("How manyu hours did you work?: "))
            pay_rate = int(input("Enter your hourly payrate here: "))

            #display the gross pay
            gross_pay = hours * pay_rate
            return gross_pay
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: Nope')
```

To fix your recursive call would look like:

```
def input2():
    try:
        #we're first getting the number of hours that the user is working. 
        hours = int(input("How manyu hours did you work?: "))
        pay_rate = int(input("Enter your hourly payrate here: "))

        #display the gross pay
        gross_pay = hours * pay_rate
    except ValueError:
        print('Error: Nope')
        gross_pay = input2()

    return gross_pay
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your indentation, the function only returns anything in the Except block. If you pass through all the Try stuff without an error, you never get to the 'return payment'.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed your code and here you go,

```
def main():
    payment = input2()
    print('Gross pay: $', format(payment), sep='')

def input2():
    try:
        #we're first getting the number of hours that the user is working.

        hours = int(input("How manyu hours did you work?: "))

        pay_rate = int(input("Enter your hourly payrate here: "))

        #display the gross pay
        gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

        #display the gross pay
        return gross_pay
    except ValueError
        print('Error: Nope')
        return input2()


main()
```

It show output this on getting correct input,
[image]

On getting incorrect input it will show this,
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can safely return payment in the exception, if there is an error with one of the inputs it'll come out None.

Comment: @Spencer it also loses any return from the recursive call... the proper return should be `return input2()`

Comment: @AChampion Good point. Theoretically he could just pop the return outside of the exception (un-indent it) and that would give the "desired" answer, however I don't think this is a very good idea overall.

Comment: @AChampion - it shouldn't work for all exceptions. Anything other than a value error on the int conversion should propagate up the stack.

Comment: @Nikhil see comment above - you aren't capturing the return of the recursive call in the exception block.

Comment: @tdelaney very true, I was focusing on the logic and missed that.

Comment: Don't catch a naked exception. It masks other errors. Turn it back!

Comment: ... and that really should be a `return input2()` in the exception. There doesn't need to be another return after the except block. The code can never get there.

Comment: Guys Suggest me what more errors can come except valueError.

Comment: @Nikhil NameError (user puts in a string not a num)

Comment: @Spencer whenever i put a string or a number, during the conversion to integer it returns value error.

Comment: @Nikhil sorry, I ran my code in 2.7 which throws a NameError. My bad.

Comment: No problem bro!